# Kill all filtered oozie jobs

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

How to kill all filtered oozie jobs?

For example I want to kill all oozie jobs, with next condition:

```
oozie jobs -filter name=calculationx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (note that there are some field missing, like Oozie host & ect'):

```
for jobId in `oozie jobs -filter name=calculationx | grep RUNNING | cut -d" " -f1`
do
    echo "Killing job ${jobId}"
    job -kill ${jobId}
done
```